# azure function app python-500 internal error

Tags: azure-functions

I have created a jiratosnowflakedemo application and tried hosting using azure functions core tools from the terminal. I can see, The deployment is successful.
but it always throws 500 Internal server errors.

The local deployment worked very well though.

I have deployed from visual studio code and the code has been executed successfully in vs code too but raising errors in the portal

error at azure functionapp

[image]

error at azure portal console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you deployed python azure function to azure, then you should be forced to deploy to Linux OS.

500 error is a server side error, and it is useless(If your function has any problem, it will throw out this error.). So you need to check the logs of your azure function.

If you are based on Linux consumption plan, then it should be unable to go to Kudu. If you are based on Linux premium plan or Linux App service plan, then you can go to Kudu to check the log stream.

But you have a easier way to get the logs. Just need to use application insights to monitor the azure function:

[image]